# Twitter Bootstrap Landing Page. Clearing divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a landing page with bootstrap. The top divs are working fine, but the div on the second row is being pushed down by the larger div on top. Is there a way to make the blue div clear the red div so that it is directly under the top left div? Here is the link to the landing page. http://gabbatech.com/files/rakutenAdWords.html

Comment: Questions containing only links to outside sites are off-topic. Please post a small snippet of relevant code here. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Is this what you want? http://imgur.com/PL6KOcD

Comment: Here is a small snippet of the code.                                                                  <div class="container" id="adWordsImageDiv">
 
 
  <div class="row">
  
   <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
    <img src="images/adwords.png" class="img-responsive"/>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12" id="formDiv">
    form div content
   </div>
  
  
   <div class="col-md-7 cos-xs-12" id="learnDiv">
    learn div
   </div>
   
   
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: The blue div is far too low and is being pushed down by the red div. Is there a way to clear the effect of the red div?

Comment: @Shekhar Yes very close! As long as the blue div does not go over the picture then that is exactly what I want!

Comment: Where is the picture dude? Or at least put an image of what you want!

Comment: Sorry about that. The picture with both of the divs is in this link. http://gabbatech.com/files/rakutenAdWords.html I'm fairly sure what you've done is the solution I'm looking for. How did you do it? @Shekhar

Comment: This link also doesnt have picture.

Comment: That's weird...I'm not sure why it's not showing up. What exactly was it that you did in your example that you posted on imgur.com/PL6KOcD ?

Comment: I'm pretty much trying to create a carbon copy of this page. http://marketing.rakuten.com/adwords-audit where the blue div is the text under the picture and the red div is the form to the right of the picture.